# Do photons form bound states?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, elementary-particles

Since photons do not have electric charge, they do not interact via the electromagnetic force. They are also reported to be devoid of any colour-charge, so interaction via the strong force is ruled out as well. That is all one could say as a layperson with no training in QFT.

Is there any subtle non-classical effect/phenomena in which photons form bound states among themselves?

If yes, does it make sense to ask whether these states extend to macroscopic gaseous/liquid/solid structures?

(Now photons carry energy and this of course lets them interact via gravity and form bound systems, albeit very weak bound system of astronomical radii, but this is not what I mean.)

Comment: I haven't read this but it might be of interest: [Observation of three-photon bound states in a quantum nonlinear medium](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01478)

Comment: This isn't quite what you're asking, but you might find [photon BECs](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/centre-for-cold-matter/research/photon-bec/) interesting.